# Get first and last stops per state in chronological order

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that tracks vehicle stops per state. A vehicle for example may make multiple stops in one state, enter another state, and then return to the same state in a given day. Here is a sample of what I mean:

```
VehicleID | State | LocationDate            | EventType
-------------------------------------------------------
1         | KY    | 2013-02-10 05:09:00.000 | Delivery
1         | KY    | 2013-02-10 05:45:00.000 | Delivery
1         | KY    | 2013-02-10 06:10:00.000 | Gas
1         | IN    | 2013-02-10 08:33:00.000 | Delivery
1         | KY    | 2013-02-10 10:13:00.000 | Delivery
```

I would like to get the first and last stops times per state in chronological order. If there is only 1 row for that state that is next in the list, list that row again. So for instance, I'm looking for the following:

```
VehicleID | State | LocationDate            | FirstOrLast
---------------------------------------------------------
1         | KY    | 2013-02-10 05:09:00.000 | First
1         | KY    | 2013-02-10 06:10:00.000 | Last
1         | IN    | 2013-02-10 08:33:00.000 | First
1         | IN    | 2013-02-10 08:33:00.000 | Last
1         | KY    | 2013-02-10 10:13:00.000 | First
1         | KY    | 2013-02-10 10:13:00.000 | Last
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you want to add a grouping identifier for consecutive states.  You can do this using a difference of row numbers.  This is a clever way to identify groups of sequential rows.

Then, with that information, you can use `row_number()` to get the information you want.  Because you want rows to be duplicated, I am going to suggest a `union all` approach:

```
with g as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by vehicleId, grp, state order by LocationDate) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by vehicleId, grp, state order by LocationDate desc) as seqnum_desc
      from (select t.*,
                   (row_number() over (partition by VehicleID order by LocationDate) -
                    row_number() over (partition by VehicleID, State order by LocationDate)
                   ) as grp
            from t
           ) t
     )
select g.*, 'First' as FirstOrLast
from g
where seqnum_asc = 1
union all
select g.*, 'Last' as FirstOrLast
from g
where seqnum_desc = 1;
```